# Effective file permissions tool's api in windows

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, file-permissions

Starting from Windows Server 2003, Windows included a new tool which calculates the effective permissions for a user (basically it resolves all groups access and takes care of all "deny" permissions as well). An example in point is that a user A belongs to groups B and C. B has been denied read permissions on a file F, while C has been allowed read and write permissions on the file and I want to calculate the effective permissions user A has on file F. 
This tool is available on Windows Server 2003,Vista,7 and Server 2008 by right clicking on a file and going to properties -> security -> advanced -> effective permissions.

What I need is an API in C# which does the same job. The most common FILE API returns access rules (class FileAccessRules), but there seems to be no direct way to calculate effective permissions from these set of access rules. 
Note: I do not want to process effective permissions in the code if at all possible, but am ready to do so as a last resort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a function called GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl in advapi32.dll. This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.
Actually, the effective permissions tool uses the AuthzAccessCheck function. I used it, and did not find performance degradation by as much as I thought. (However, I am told that Authz does not include the "integrity" concept available in windows 7 and above, and may report wrong results.)

Answer (score 3):

Some quick code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.AccessControl;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static extern uint GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(IntPtr pDacl, ref TRUSTEE pTrustee, ref ACCESS_MASK pAccessRights);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
        struct TRUSTEE
        {
            IntPtr pMultipleTrustee; // must be null
            public int MultipleTrusteeOperation;
            public TRUSTEE_FORM TrusteeForm;
            public TRUSTEE_TYPE TrusteeType;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string ptstrName;
        }

        enum TRUSTEE_FORM
        {
            TRUSTEE_IS_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_NAME,
            TRUSTEE_BAD_FORM,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_SID,
            TRUSTEE_IS_OBJECTS_AND_NAME
        }

        enum TRUSTEE_TYPE {
          TRUSTEE_IS_UNKNOWN,
          TRUSTEE_IS_USER,
          TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP,
          TRUSTEE_IS_DOMAIN,
          TRUSTEE_IS_ALIAS,
          TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP,
          TRUSTEE_IS_DELETED,
          TRUSTEE_IS_INVALID,
          TRUSTEE_IS_COMPUTER 
        } 

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern uint GetNamedSecurityInfo(
            string pObjectName,
            SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
            SECURITY_INFORMATION SecurityInfo,
            out IntPtr pSidOwner,
            out IntPtr pSidGroup,
            out IntPtr pDacl,
            out IntPtr pSacl,
            out IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);

        enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
        {
            DELETE = 0x00010000,
            READ_CONTROL = 0x00020000,
            WRITE_DAC = 0x00040000,
            WRITE_OWNER = 0x00080000,
            SYNCHRONIZE = 0x00100000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_REQUIRED = 0x000f0000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ = 0x00020000,
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_WRITE = 0x00020000,
            STANDARD_RIGHTS_EXECUTE = 0x00020000,

            STANDARD_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x001f0000,

            SPECIFIC_RIGHTS_ALL = 0x0000ffff,

            ACCESS_SYSTEM_SECURITY = 0x01000000,

            MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x02000000,

            GENERIC_READ = 0x80000000,
            GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000,
            GENERIC_EXECUTE = 0x20000000,
            GENERIC_ALL = 0x10000000,

            DESKTOP_READOBJECTS = 0x00000001,
            DESKTOP_CREATEWINDOW = 0x00000002,
            DESKTOP_CREATEMENU = 0x00000004,
            DESKTOP_HOOKCONTROL = 0x00000008,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALRECORD = 0x00000010,
            DESKTOP_JOURNALPLAYBACK = 0x00000020,
            DESKTOP_ENUMERATE = 0x00000040,
            DESKTOP_WRITEOBJECTS = 0x00000080,
            DESKTOP_SWITCHDESKTOP = 0x00000100,

            WINSTA_ENUMDESKTOPS = 0x00000001,
            WINSTA_READATTRIBUTES = 0x00000002,
            WINSTA_ACCESSCLIPBOARD = 0x00000004,
            WINSTA_CREATEDESKTOP = 0x00000008,
            WINSTA_WRITEATTRIBUTES = 0x00000010,
            WINSTA_ACCESSGLOBALATOMS = 0x00000020,
            WINSTA_EXITWINDOWS = 0x00000040,
            WINSTA_ENUMERATE = 0x00000100,
            WINSTA_READSCREEN = 0x00000200,

            WINSTA_ALL_ACCESS = 0x0000037f
        }

        [Flags]
        enum SECURITY_INFORMATION : uint
        {
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001,
            GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000002,
            DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004,
            SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000008,
            UNPROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x10000000,
            UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x20000000,
            PROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x40000000,
            PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x80000000
        }

        enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
        {
            SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE = 0,
            SE_FILE_OBJECT,
            SE_SERVICE,
            SE_PRINTER,
            SE_REGISTRY_KEY,
            SE_LMSHARE,
            SE_KERNEL_OBJECT,
            SE_WINDOW_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT,
            SE_DS_OBJECT_ALL,
            SE_PROVIDER_DEFINED_OBJECT,
            SE_WMIGUID_OBJECT,
            SE_REGISTRY_WOW64_32KEY
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            

        String user = "DOMAIN\\USER";
        String Path = "C:\\";

            IntPtr pSidOwner, pSidGroup, pDacl, pSacl, pSecurityDescriptor;
            ACCESS_MASK mask = new ACCESS_MASK();
            uint ret = GetNamedSecurityInfo(Path, 
                SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT, 
                SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                out pSidOwner, out pSidGroup, out pDacl, out pSacl, out pSecurityDescriptor);

            TRUSTEE t = new TRUSTEE();
            t.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_FORM.TRUSTEE_IS_NAME;
            t.TrusteeType= TRUSTEE_TYPE.TRUSTEE_IS_USER;
            t.ptstrName = user;
            ret = GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl(pDacl, ref t , ref mask);

            if ((mask & ACCESS_MASK.READ_CONTROL) == ACCESS_MASK.READ_CONTROL)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Read");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("No Read");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is freezing on my systems (Win 7 and XP). ANy idea?

Comment: This worked for me as long as the user has permission to view the file or folder.  If view permissions and read permissions are denied to the user for a folder or file, a mask isn't returned and this incorrectly returns "read" (I had it return "true" instead).  The "cool" thing is I could use it to bypass view permissions and see folders which are ordinarily hidden from me.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the effective permission of an user over a file/folder by using the Authz API provided by Windows.
Follow the below link.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff394768(v=vs.85).aspx and also this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637(v=vs.85).aspx. I have tried this out in all versions of Windows starting from Windows server 2003 and got fairly good performance.