# c# - How to determine if a certain user has (effective) read-rights on a file or folder?

Tags: c#, active-directory, filesystems

I would like to know if a user (known by its name in the active directory) has effective read rights (sharerights and nfts rights) on a certain file or folder.

I do not have not the credentials of the user only its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446637%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which is present in the advapi32.dll.

You can try out the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6536955/1012641)

Comment: GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl always freezes with the provided code - no return values. (Win 7) Any idea?

Comment: It worked! Thank you! BUT: On NAS systems (Synology) it is not returning the correct users. Any idea?

Comment: Hi Martin! I have no idea about NAS. But give me some time

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the System.Security.AccessControl; namespace as well, it might provide what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks. I guess its only for nfts not for share permissions. Right?

Comment: It is possible thats the case did a little bit of searching and I did see this,http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.homeserver.sdk.interop.v1.whsinfoclass.aspx .  This here shows some implementation of that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425864.aspx .