# memberOf property only showing groups in the same domain even if it has cross-domain memberships

Tags: filter, active-directory, ldap, cross-domain

I am trying to figure out how to query AD for a group and get its `memberOf` attribute to show *all* the members, even cross-domain ones.

I will give an example:

- I have two domains:

  - `one.company.com`
  - `two.company.com`
- I have three groups:

  - `one\group1`
  - `one\group2`
  - `two\group3`
- `one\group1` is a member of `one\group2` and `two\group3`

I am trying to write a query to find all `memberOf` for `one\group1`.

No matter what query I try, the `memberOf` attribute only returns `one\group2`.

- `<GC://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(distinguishedName=CN=group1,OU=....,DC=one,DC=company,DC=com));name,memberOf;subtree`
- `<GC://DC=one,DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(distinguishedName=CN=group1,OU=....,DC=one,DC=company,DC=com));name,memberOf;subtree`
- `<LDAP://DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(distinguishedName=CN=group1,OU=....,DC=one,DC=company,DC=com));name,memberOf;subtree`
- `<LDAP://DC=one,DC=company,DC=com>;(&(objectCategory=group)(objectClass=group)(distinguishedName=CN=group1,OU=....,DC=one,DC=company,DC=com));name,memberOf;subtree`

I am trying to do it this way because ultimately there are multiple groups I want to get `memberOf` for so if I can get this to work then I can just put them all in `(|...)` in the search filter and only make one call.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574449/active-directory-cross-domains/39583452#39583452

Comment: @oldovets Thank you!