# getting effective folder permissions for user

Tags: c#, permissions

Is there api in .net for getting effective folder permissions for user?
I know how get permissions by using `DirectorySecurity.GetAccessRules().
But in this case I should manually analyze all permissions for user: permissions for groups, that include the user, inherited permissions and user permission for folder.

Is there a function in the Windows API that can return these permissions via platform invoke?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Effective file permissions tool's api in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3021698/effective-file-permissions-tools-api-in-windows)

Comment: The solution is described in this topic doesn't work.  The function GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl is sensetive to order of access rules.

Comment: And that's a problem why? Regular access checks are also sensitive to the order of access rules. Can you show an example where `GetEffectiveRightsFromAcl` doesn't do what you want it to do, and what you're expecting to happen instead?

Answer (score -1):

class Program
    {
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, Pack = 4)]
        public struct LUID
        {
            public uint LowPart;
            public int HighPart;
        }

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST
    {
        public int DesiredAccess;
        public byte[] PrincipalSelfSid;
        public OBJECT_TYPE_LIST[] ObjectTypeList;
        public int ObjectTypeListLength;
        public IntPtr OptionalArguments;
    };
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct OBJECT_TYPE_LIST
    {
        OBJECT_TYPE_LEVEL Level;
        int Sbz;
        IntPtr ObjectType;
    };

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY
    {
        public int ResultListLength;
        public IntPtr GrantedAccessMask;
        public IntPtr SaclEvaluationResults;
        public IntPtr Error;
    };

    public enum OBJECT_TYPE_LEVEL : int
    {
        ACCESS_OBJECT_GUID = 0,
        ACCESS_PROPERTY_SET_GUID = 1,
        ACCESS_PROPERTY_GUID = 2,
        ACCESS_MAX_LEVEL = 4
    };


    enum AUTHZ_RM_FLAG : uint
    {
        AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_AUDIT = 1,
        AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_INITIALIZE_UNDER_IMPERSONATION = 2,
        AUTHZ_RM_FLAG_NO_CENTRAL_ACCESS_POLICIES = 4,
    }



    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern uint GetNamedSecurityInfo(
        string pObjectName,
        SE_OBJECT_TYPE ObjectType,
        SECURITY_INFORMATION SecurityInfo,
        out IntPtr pSidOwner,
        out IntPtr pSidGroup,
        out IntPtr pDacl,
        out IntPtr pSacl,
        out IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor);
    [DllImport("authz.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "AuthzInitializeContextFromSid", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern public bool AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(
                                           int Flags,
                                           IntPtr UserSid ,
                                           IntPtr AuthzResourceManager,
                                           IntPtr pExpirationTime,
                                           LUID Identitifier,
                                           IntPtr DynamicGroupArgs,
                                           out IntPtr pAuthzClientContext
                                           );



    [DllImport("authz.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint = "AuthzInitializeResourceManager", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern public bool AuthzInitializeResourceManager(
                                    int flags,
                                    IntPtr pfnAccessCheck,
                                    IntPtr pfnComputeDynamicGroups,
                                    IntPtr pfnFreeDynamicGroups,
                                    string name,
                                    out IntPtr rm
                                    );
    [DllImport("authz.dll", EntryPoint = "AuthzAccessCheck", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AuthzAccessCheck(int flags, 
                                                IntPtr hAuthzClientContext,
                                                 ref AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST pRequest, 
                                                 IntPtr AuditEvent,
                                                 IntPtr pSecurityDescriptor, 
                                                byte[] OptionalSecurityDescriptorArray,
                                                int OptionalSecurityDescriptorCount, 
                                                ref AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY pReply,
                                                out IntPtr phAccessCheckResults);

    enum ACCESS_MASK : uint
    {
        FILE_TRAVERSE = 0x20,FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x1,FILE_READ_DATA = 0x1,FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80,FILE_READ_EA = 0x8,FILE_ADD_FILE = 0x2,FILE_WRITE_DATA = 0x2,FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY = 0x4,FILE_APPEND_DATA = 0x4,FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES = 0x100,FILE_WRITE_EA = 0x10,FILE_DELETE_CHILD = 0x40,DELETE = 0x10000,READ_CONTROL = 0x20000,WRITE_DAC = 0x40000,
        WRITE_OWNER = 0x80000,
    }

    [Flags]
    enum SECURITY_INFORMATION : uint
    {
        OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000001,
        GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000002,
        DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000004,
        SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x00000008,
        UNPROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x10000000,
        UNPROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x20000000,
        PROTECTED_SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x40000000,
        PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION = 0x80000000
    }

    enum SE_OBJECT_TYPE
    {
        SE_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_TYPE = 0,
        SE_FILE_OBJECT,
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //String UserName = "NT Authority\\Authenticated Users";
        do {
            Console.WriteLine("UserName:");
            String UserName = Console.ReadLine();
            SecurityIdentifier sid = null;
            NTAccount ac = new NTAccount(UserName);
            try
            {
                sid = (SecurityIdentifier)ac.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not a group or user");
                continue;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Path:");
            String Path = Console.ReadLine();

            if (!(File.Exists(Path) || Directory.Exists(Path)))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid Path");
                continue;
            }


            IntPtr pSidOwner, pSidGroup, pDacl, pSacl, pSecurityDescriptor;
            ACCESS_MASK mask = new ACCESS_MASK();
            uint ret = GetNamedSecurityInfo(Path,
                                            SE_OBJECT_TYPE.SE_FILE_OBJECT,
                                            SECURITY_INFORMATION.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SECURITY_INFORMATION.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION | SECURITY_INFORMATION.GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
                                            out pSidOwner,
                                            out pSidGroup, 
                                            out pDacl, 
                                            out pSacl,
                                            out pSecurityDescriptor);

            IntPtr hManager = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool f = AuthzInitializeResourceManager(1, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, null, out hManager);

            byte[] bytes = new byte[sid.BinaryLength];
            sid.GetBinaryForm(bytes, 0);
            String _psUserSid = "";
            foreach (byte si in bytes)
            {
                _psUserSid += si;
            }

            LUID unusedSid = new LUID();
            IntPtr UserSid = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(bytes.Length);
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, UserSid, bytes.Length);
            IntPtr pClientContext = IntPtr.Zero;

            if (f)
            {
                f = AuthzInitializeContextFromSid(0, UserSid, hManager, IntPtr.Zero, unusedSid, IntPtr.Zero, out pClientContext);


                AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST request = new AUTHZ_ACCESS_REQUEST();
                request.DesiredAccess = 0x02000000;
                request.PrincipalSelfSid = null;
                request.ObjectTypeList = null;
                request.ObjectTypeListLength = 0;
                request.OptionalArguments = IntPtr.Zero;

                AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY reply = new AUTHZ_ACCESS_REPLY();
                reply.GrantedAccessMask = IntPtr.Zero;
                reply.ResultListLength = 0;
                reply.SaclEvaluationResults = IntPtr.Zero;
                IntPtr AccessReply = IntPtr.Zero;
                reply.Error = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1020);
                reply.GrantedAccessMask = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(uint));
                reply.ResultListLength = 1;
                int i = 0;
                Dictionary<String, String> rightsmap = new Dictionary<String, String>();
                List<string> effectivePermissionList = new List<string>();
                string[] rights = new string[14] { "Full Control", "Traverse Folder / execute file", "List folder / read data", "Read attributes", "Read extended attributes", "Create files / write files", "Create folders / append data", "Write attributes", "Write extended attributes", "Delete subfolders and files", "Delete", "Read permission", "Change permission", "Take ownership" };
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_TRAVERSE", "Traverse Folder / execute file");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY", "List folder / read data");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_DATA", "List folder / read data");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES", "Read attributes");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_READ_EA", "Read extended attributes");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_ADD_FILE", "Create files / write files");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_DATA", "Create files /  write files");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_ADD_SUBDIRECTORY", "Create folders / append data");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_APPEND_DATA", "Create folders / append data");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_ATTRIBUTES", "Write attributes");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_WRITE_EA", "Write extended attributes");
                rightsmap.Add("FILE_DELETE_CHILD", "Delete subfolders and files");
                rightsmap.Add("DELETE", "Delete");
                rightsmap.Add("READ_CONTROL", "Read permission");
                rightsmap.Add("WRITE_DAC", "Change permission");
                rightsmap.Add("WRITE_OWNER", "Take ownership");


                f = AuthzAccessCheck(0, pClientContext, ref request, IntPtr.Zero, pSecurityDescriptor, null, 0, ref reply, out AccessReply);
                if (f)
                {
                    int granted_access = Marshal.ReadInt32(reply.GrantedAccessMask);

                     mask = (ACCESS_MASK)granted_access;

                    foreach (ACCESS_MASK item in Enum.GetValues(typeof(ACCESS_MASK)))
                    {
                        if ((mask & item) == item)
                        {
                            effectivePermissionList.Add(rightsmap[item.ToString()]);
                            i++;
                        }

                    }
                }
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(reply.GrantedAccessMask);




                if (i == 16)
                {
                    effectivePermissionList.Insert(0, "Full Control");
                }
                Console.WriteLine(".......................");
                foreach (string r in rights)
                {
                    if (effectivePermissionList.Contains(r))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(r);
                    }
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine("_________________________________________________\n");
        } while (true);

       // Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer requires some explanation on whats happening in the code.